# Setting MultiColumn as index has issues with index names

Tags: python, pandas

Here is how I create my multi column table:

```
whatFields = ['mean', 'mom_2', 'n']
groupbyFields = ['foo', 'bar']
topFields = ['desc']*len(groupbyFields)
topFields += ['price']*len(whatFields)
topFields += ['units']*len(whatFields)
bottomFields = groupbyFields + whatFields + whatFields
resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([topFields, bottomFields]))
indexFields = [('desc', field) for field in groupbyFields]
resultsDf.set_index(indexFields, inplace=True)
```

Here's the empty result:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(price, mean), (price, mom_2), (price, n), (units, mean), (units, mom_2), (units, n)]
Index: []

>>> resultsDf.index
Out[2]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[], []],
           labels=[[], []],
           names=[('desc', 'foo'), ('desc', 'bar')])
```

However, after filling up, it looks like this:

```
                                     price            units           
                                      mean mom_2    n  mean mom_2    n
(desc, foo) (desc, bar)                                  
1500002071  4292                       NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
            4246                       NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
            342                        NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
            104                        NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
            4218                      2.59     0    1   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

the problem is that index fields have these weird names in tuple form, while columns have "proper" names now in the multi column shape.

You might think this is because they're an index. No:

```
  (desc, foo) (desc, bar) price            units           
                                        mean mom_2    n  mean mom_2    n
0  1500002071                     4292   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1  1500002071                     4246   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
2  1500002071                      342   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
3  1500002071                      104   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
4  1500002071                     4218  2.59     0    1   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Why is the index not following the columns in terms of multi layout? Ultimatively, I'd like to access the index simply via `foo` and `bar` (or real multi index, at least not this pseudo tuples).

How could I achieve that? Is there a better way to generate my empty df to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? I wasn't exactly sure how you wanted to main index set up.

Two ways:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd
i
In [3]: import itertools as it

In [4]: whatFields = ['mean', 'mom_2', 'n']
   ...: groupbyFields = ['foo', 'bar']
   ...: topFields= ['price', 'units']
   ...: descriptions = [11, 22, 33, 44]
   ...:
   ...: top_index = list(it.product(topFields, whatFields))
   ...:
   ...: main_index = list(it.product(descriptions, groupbyFields))
   ...: main_index
Out[4]:
[(11, 'foo'),
 (11, 'bar'),
 (22, 'foo'),
 (22, 'bar'),
 (33, 'foo'),
 (33, 'bar'),
 (44, 'foo'),
 (44, 'bar')]

In [5]: top_index
Out[5]:
[('price', 'mean'),
 ('price', 'mom_2'),
 ('price', 'n'),
 ('units', 'mean'),
 ('units', 'mom_2'),
 ('units', 'n')]

In [6]: resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(main_index)
   ...:                                  .set_names(['desc', 'something']),
   ...:                          columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(top_index),
   ...:                         data=np.random.rand(len(main_index), len(top_index))
   ...:                         ).sort_index()

In [7]: resultsDf
Out[7]:
                   price                         units
                    mean     mom_2         n      mean     mom_2         n
desc something
11   bar        0.415331  0.153503  0.750690  0.505439  0.781057  0.102450
     foo        0.444163  0.921779  0.587966  0.988859  0.747277  0.645065
22   bar        0.205548  0.835086  0.630778  0.936277  0.587607  0.644636
     foo        0.907772  0.927121  0.457286  0.881467  0.091484  0.217839
33   bar        0.207454  0.670291  0.609697  0.024396  0.808362  0.738188
     foo        0.838015  0.058354  0.804375  0.704137  0.760060  0.638933
44   bar        0.577411  0.085774  0.394033  0.798052  0.107777  0.852888
     foo        0.528873  0.902225  0.098982  0.611146  0.122890  0.887364
```

Or:

```
In [10]: resultsDf = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(top_index),
    ...:                         data=np.random.rand(len(main_index), len(top_index)) )
    ...:
    ...: resultsDf['desc'], resultsDf['something'] = zip(*main_index)
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: resultsDf = resultsDf.set_index(['desc', 'something']).sort_index()
    ...:

In [11]: resultsDf
Out[11]:
                   price                         units
                    mean     mom_2         n      mean     mom_2         n
desc something
11   foo        0.205574  0.673159  0.772009  0.598809  0.070022  0.332420
     bar        0.844376  0.602825  0.433186  0.420408  0.299380  0.354098
22   foo        0.341226  0.489068  0.784226  0.721386  0.866248  0.113838
     bar        0.729578  0.209731  0.533399  0.993587  0.340383  0.895143
33   foo        0.629427  0.285344  0.634120  0.940294  0.378314  0.416081
     bar        0.251746  0.022984  0.415058  0.322093  0.719954  0.251906
44   foo        0.247829  0.085609  0.680114  0.760157  0.493465  0.659629
     bar        0.667425  0.749589  0.578318  0.190334  0.131337  0.090083

In [13]: resultsDf.loc[(22, "bar")]
Out[13]:
price  mean     0.729578
       mom_2    0.209731
       n        0.533399
units  mean     0.993587
       mom_2    0.340383
       n        0.895143
Name: (22, bar), dtype: float64

In [14]: resultsDf.loc[(22, "bar"), "units"]
Out[14]:
mean     0.993587
mom_2    0.340383
n        0.895143
Name: (22, bar), dtype: float64
```